# GoAccess date/time/log format error

Tags: nginx, goaccess

When running GoAccess with my Nginx log file I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error has occurred
Error occured at: src/goaccess.c - main - 1017
Nothing valid to process. Verify your date/time/log format.
```

Log lines example:

```
example.com 66.87.119.148 - - [27/May/2016:10:45:50 +0000] "GET /uploads/5458ac234488de92aa9cda3a/logo300.png HTTP/1.1" 200 11153 "http://example.com/page1" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13D15 Safari/601.1"
example.com 207.250.34.193 - - [27/May/2016:10:45:50 +0000] "GET /assets/5.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://example.com/page2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
```

~/.goaccessrc:

```
time-format %H:%M:%S
date-format %d/%b/%Y
log-format %^ %h - - [%d] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```

executing like this:

```
goaccess -f /example.com_access.log -p ~/.goaccessrc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this in your Goaccess configuration file, it works on my end:

```
 log-format %v %h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
 date-format %d/%b/%Y
 time-format %H:%M:%S
```